# Using an AJAX GET request to get an object

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, object, get

I have a program using the node.js express framework.
In there I have a file called index.js, that handles the server side of things.
It has an object (latestResults = {}), that stores json objects assigned to timestamps(latestResults[timestamp] = jsonObj).

In a file called visualization.js(client) I want to access that object.
I wanted to use an AJAX GET request, but frankly I don't know how that would look like and I couldn't find anything on the web. 
How could the url look like?

Comment: can you show some code in your `index.js` file. how is latestResults stored?

Comment: var latestResults = {}
it gets filled with json objects that are assigned to timestamps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having refined my knowledge og what the OP is asking for I will try to answer like this:

For mounting a rest endpoint to serve the client with the latestResult object you will have to do something similar to:

```
var app = express();
app.get('/latestResults', function (req, res) { res.send (global.latestResults); });
```

and for fetching the object you can use jQuery (https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/):

```
jQuery.get( '/latestResults', function (latestResults) { visualize(latestResults); });
```

or angularjs (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http), or as I prefer - the fetch polyfill since this is already implemented in some browsers (https://github.com/github/fetch)

Comment: I assume that latestResults is stored as a global variable on the server side.

Comment: That's great thank you! I will try that as soon as I can.

Answer (score 0):

A simple ajax code would look like this:

create a json object data to send with the request, if required.

```
var data = {};
//insert values in data object.
$.ajax({
          url: 'yourUrl',
          data: data,
          processData: false,
          contentType: false,
          type: 'POST',
          dataType:'json',
          success: function(response){
              //access response variable sent from server.
          },error : function(response){
          //process error
          }});
```

your `index.js` file should handle the route at which the POST call is going and should send the variable `latestResults` in response.

Comment: are you sure, that I need to post it first?
lestestResults changes over time and I just need to access it from the client

Comment: you can do POST or GET call, that depends on your requirement and you. If your latestResults depends on client, send the updated value in the form  of data in the POST call.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can try this:

Inside index.js

```
window.myObj = (function (myObj) {

    var latestResults = {};

    myObj.getLatestResults = function () {
        return latestResults;
    }

    return myObj;

}(window.myObj || {}));
```

1. The above code uses an anonymous function to create a closure to limit the amount of global variables (window.myObj is a global variable).
2. The function receives the window.myObj variable (in case it already exists) or an empty object (in case window.myObj does exist). This is to avoid the need to include the js files in the correct order.
3. The given object will then be enriched with the function *getLatestResults* which in turn returns the latestResults object.

And inside visualization.js

```
window.myObj = (function (myObj) {

    myObj.visualize = function () {
        ...
        var data = myObj.getLatestResults()[timestamp];
        ...
    }

    return myObj;

}(window.myObj || {}));
```

1. Same procedure as in index.js. The closure receives the global variable myObj (window.myObj).
2. window.myObj is enriched with the function *visualize* (no need to do this step, but I assumed that you needed some function somewhere to do your visualization stuff).
3. The function *visualize* is then able to get a hold of *latestResults* through *myObj.getLatesResults*.

Comment: The idea is to NOT use an AJAX call at all, since you already have all the objects cached in javascript.

Comment: could you briefly explain what happens there?

Comment: Edit the question - added brief explanation.

Comment: The moment window.myObj is assigned in the file *index.js* it is available in *visualization.js*.

Comment: this doesn't work for me because I use the node.js express framework. 
I can't use window there

Comment: just remove window. from the code or use global. instead

Comment: Sorry, I seem to have misunderstood your request. I thought that you only used javascript on the client side of things.